# Does InDesign have an option to update the document accordingly to the template on which it is based on

Tags: adobe-indesign, template

This might be a very silly question, but since I'm going to start using InDesign as my "word processor" (that is, for writing), I still have to ask it.

When you create a document based on a specific template in Word or LibreOffice Writer, the template is automatically assigned to that document, and if you change the template later, and then open a document based on it, the program will ask you whether the document should be changed accordingly.

From what I understand, there is no such thing in InDesign. The templates are never "assigned", and after the document is created, it lives its own life, right?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. If you update a Master Page (Parent Page as of InDesign 2022), any pages with that page applied will update accordingly – as much as possible – but there’s no concept of whole document templates, apart from template files which just create regular, independent InDesign documents when opened. Updating children when a parent is updated is always tricky when the children can override and alter almost all of the parent’s content, which you can do in InDesign (I don’t know how LibreOffice handles it).

Comment: Thanks, Janus. (This one comment is temporary. I will remove it later.)

Comment: Well.. You *can* link text files (Word, Libre) to the Indesign file similar to images. If that *text* file changes, Indesign will ask if you want to update text.. but that has nothing to do with templates. Is this more what you are referring to? I'm wondering if using the word "template" is throwing people off. You can also place one indesign file into another.. if the placed file changes, you're asked to update. So, really, explaining *exactly* what you need may help answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InDesign does *not* have this exact functionality. An InDesign document starts with a clean page. You can add any content you want. A page might have just one text frame with text flowing from page to page (like a Word document), it might have 100s of text frames in a large diagram or it might have no text frames and only graphics and images. To make a system of templates for such complexity seems like an impossible task.

InDesign *does* have something called *Templates*, but they are like ordinary InDesign files which just automatically makes a duplicate when opened so you don't overwrite the template file. Read more about templates [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/files-templates.html).

InDesign also has the concept of a *Book* which is a wrapper around a range of documents. In a way it can be used as you describe. One of the documents is chosen as the *Style Source*. When you edit styles, color swatches, master pages etc. in the style source, the other documents of the book can be synchronized to reflect the changes. Books are (obviously) mostly meant for creating books. Long documents which consists of a range of shorter documents. Read more about books [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-book-files.html).

Besides that you can always load the styles of one document into another document manually.

For what it's worth, as a graphic designer I (perhaps surprisingly) seldom need a feature like this. Perhaps because I don't create content myself but almost exclusively receives finished texts and create layouts from that. When the layout is done, it's printed and delivered and that's that. I hardly ever have to go back and change older layouts to reflect changes in the styling of newer documents.

But I do see how templates could be helpful *in theory*. It's just really hard to imagine how changing styles globally wouldn't mess up all the documents. Remember that in InDesign you work with designed *pages* - not a never-ending roll of text like in word processors.